# Migrating Craft site to another server --- throws 404 for all pages but homepage

Tags: 404, migration

I've been asked to migrate a Craft site from one server to another.  The new server setup is the same as the server I'm migrating from.  I moved all the files in the webroot directory over to the new server and imported the database.  The homepage works just fine, just all links go to an Apache 404 and so does the admin panel.  Ideas?  Nothing is different from the other server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

99% chance that it is because the .htaccess file did not come over when you copied the files, as it is a hidden file. Copy that over to your new webroot and those interior pages should properly work.

Comment: I thought that may have been the problem a bit ago, but unfornately it's not.  The rules are the same as the other server.  Thanks for your reply though!!!:<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Is this new server set for AllowOverride All in the httpd.conf file? I.e., is it set to actually look for the htaccess file? If not, move all of the htaccess rules to a proper <Directory /your/path/to/public> directive in httpd.conf as you'll get a speed boost from bypassing htaccess, and restart Apache for them to be recognized.

Comment: Thank you!!! Yea, I was told this was a clone... not so much! Needed to AllowOverride.